# using yum list package, show only the package name without x86_64 and version number without 4.el7

Tags: yum, packages

please help me, i want using `yum list package`, show only the package name without x86_64 and version number without 4.el7.

I don't want to use `rpm -qa --qf` , because yum more accurate.

```
yum list installed
The output:
ModemManager.x86_64                   1.6.10-4.el7
ModemManager-glib.x86_64              1.6.10-4.el7
NetworkManager.x86_64                 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9
NetworkManager-adsl.x86_64            1:1.18.8-2.el7_9
NetworkManager-config-server.noarch.  1:1.18.8-2.el7_9
```

and I want the output be like this:

```
ModemManager                  1.6.10
ModemManager-glib             1.6.10
NetworkManager                1.18.8
```

Comment: not sure what option `--qf` means. but haven't you tried to use `| grep -vE ".x86_64|4.el7"`or `grep "noarch"` ?

Comment: do you mean - yum list installed  | grep -vE ".x86_64|4.el7" ?

Comment: yes, or you want to use `| sed -e 's/4.el7.*//g' -e 's/.x86_64//g` to remove specified text of every line ?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove them from the lines

Comment: give me an example output of what you get and then what the output should look like, then I can halp you

Comment: pls add this to your post and not the comments

Answer (score 0):

For the following example you have to add or change the `sed` parameters depending on the output you want to have.

```
yum list installed | \
sed -e 's/.x86_64//g'  \
-e 's/.noarch//g' \
-e 's/-[[:digit:]].el7_9//g' \
-e 's/-[[:digit:]].el[[:digit:]]//g'
```

This will remove all entries of `.x86_64 .noarch -[0-9].el7_9 -[0-9].el[0-9]`

Comment: Unfortunately , It is working for some lines only

Comment: which lines doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

yum list installed | awk 'NR>2' | cut -d' ' -f1

Adjust the awk/cut parameters based on your output.